# How to get sql result before and after a given result in array

Tags: php, mysql

I am completely perplexed as to how to do what I am attempting to do.

I have an mysql array of various numbers selected based on username. Each user will have different numbers. So an example of output would look similar to:

```
13
23
47
79
150
216
```

Again array is completely different and based entirely upon username. I am trying to determine how to get the number from the row before and the row after when I know a given number.

So for example if I know that one of the results in the array is 79, how would I determine the result before and the result after? Mind you I don't know number 79 is row 4, and I don't know the number before it is 47 nor do I know the number after is 150.

How could I get the results of the row before and after a given number?

Please avoid PDO answers if possible as I am just learning and mixing PDO and non-PDO code seems to create issues whenever I try.

Comment: I just want to clarify because of confusing terminology. MySQL doesn't exactly have "arrays", but do you mean to say that the list of numbers is a rowset returned by MySQL?  The set you have is ordered numerically. Are they always sorted that way?

Comment: Thanks the question was confusing because I was being stupid. Thanks for attempting :)

Answer (score 0):

This was one of those issues where I spent to long programming and I was overlooking the logical answer.

Logically I need to set a loop counter on the original array so that not only the number is returned, but also the row containing said number. If I knew that the number is 79, I should have also been able to determine that it was row 4, and because of that, set a variable for row 3 and row 5.

So the simple stupid answer to my retarded question was, use a loop counter when determining the number. :)